# Build FFmpeg with libaom using MSYS

Tags: ffmpeg, configure, pkg-config

I'm trying to build `FFmpeg` (version `4.3.1`) with `--enable-libaom` for `Windows` using `MSYS` and `Microsoft Visual C++`.

Configure script says: `ERROR: aom >= 1.0.0 not found using pkg-config`

But I have `libaom` (built it from sources) and paths to it are specified:

```
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%~dp0..\..\libaom-build\prebuilt\include;
set LIB=%LIB%;%~dp0..\..\libaom-build\prebuilt\windows\x64\lib;
```

This is how I call the configuration script:

```
./configure --prefix=$PWD/../../prebuilt/windows/x64 --toolchain=msvc --extra-cflags="-MD" --arch=x64 --disable-x86asm --disable-iconv --disable-network \
--enable-filter=stereo3d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d \
--extra-cflags="-I$PWD/../../../zlib-build/prebuilt/include -I$PWD/../../../libpng-build/prebuilt/include -I$PWD/../../../lame-build/prebuilt/include -I$PWD/../../../libaom-build/prebuilt/include -I$PWD/../../../libdav1d-build/prebuilt/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L$PWD/../../../lame-build/prebuilt/windows/x64/lib -L$PWD/../../../libaom-build/prebuilt/windows/x64/lib -L$PWD/../../../libdav1d-build/prebuilt/windows/x64/lib"
```

Comment: Share the last few lines of `ffbuild/config.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gyan for pointing me out to `ffbuild/config.log`.

I've created `aom.pc` file and put it into `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`:

```
# libaom pkg-config.

Name: aom
Description: AV1 codec library v2.0.2.
Version: 2.0.2
Requires:
Conflicts:
Libs: -laom
Libs.private:
Cflags:
```

This helped.